# iOS-Charts - Display X-Axis from oldest to newest (using descending-sorted values)

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-charts

I'm building a temperature line chart using Charts for iOS.

I have a `timeline` with an array of seconds from now `time` and the corresponding array of temperature `temp`.

example:

```
timeline.time = [504,633,777,803,1020]
timeline.temp = [87,88,88,86,87]
```

I would like my chart to show temperatures from the oldest seconds from now on the left, and newest on the right, but when I order my array of `time` in descending order, my chart is empty. Is there a way to show a chart with the smallest value on x axis on the left, and biggest value on the right?

Here is my current code:

```
    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()

    //loop in env data
    for i in 0..<timeline.temp.count {
        let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeline.time[i]), y: Double(timeline.temp[i]))
        lineChartEntry.append(value)
    }

    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "Temperature (°F)")
    line1.colors = [UIColor.irbLightGreenColor()]
    line1.mode = .horizontalBezier
    line1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    line1.lineWidth = 3

    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: line1)

    data.setDrawValues(false)
    temperatureLineChartView.data = data
```

If I try to reverse the array like so: `Array(timeline.time[i].reversed())` / `Array(timeline.temp[i].reversed())` my chart is empty.

Comment: There's no way to answer this without seeing how you are creating the chart UI.

Comment: I'm using iOS Charts [https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) My controller has a `temperatureLineChartView: LineChartView!` then on ViewDidLoad I have the code I posted in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you need to do is display the data in reversed order, then you can call the range's `reversed()` method to change the index and leave the data alone.

```
for i in (0..<timeline.temp.count).reversed() {
    let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeline.time[i]), y: Double(timeline.temp[i]))
    lineChartEntry.append(value)
}
```

Your attempt at `Array(timeline.time[i].reversed())` was quite literally trying to reverse the i'th element of time[], not access the i'th element of **reversed** time[]. I don't see how that even compiled.